# (Complex Numbers) I've almost solved this problem but can't understand which particular case is this problem talking about.

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

> If $x,y,z$ are the roots of the equation $x^3 + px^2 + qx + p = 0$, prove that $\tan^{-1}x + \tan^{-1}y + \tan^{-1}z = n\pi$ **except in one particular case**.

Note: $n$ is any integer.

Comment: Try to use $\arctan{u}+\arctan{v} = \arctan [(u+v)/(1-uv)] \mod(\pi)$.

Comment: You're using $x$ for two different things. $x$ can't be the root of an equation if it is also the unknown variable.

Comment: As others have noted, the exception is $q=1$. In this case the cubic is $(x^2+1)(x+p)$, so the roots are $-p,\,\pm i$.

Comment: @Arthur my back , sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given polynomial is  $n^3+pn^2+qn+p=0$  $\qquad$

NOTE: im using $n$ as the variable to avoid confusion with it being the root

[Vieta's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas)  gives us that $x+y+z= -p$

$ xy+yz+zx = q$

$xyz = -p$

$\tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(y)+\tan^{-1}(z) = \tan^{-1}\bigg( \frac{x+y+z -xyz}{1-(xy+yz+zx)}\bigg)$

$\tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(y)+\tan^{-1}(z) = \tan^{-1}\bigg( \frac{-p+p}{1-q}\bigg)$

$\tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(y)+\tan^{-1}(z) = \tan^{-1}(0)$

$\implies\tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(y)+\tan^{-1}(z) = n\pi$ $\qquad ,n\in Z$

Notice that the above is not defined when $1-q = 0\implies q =1$

Comment: thanks , i got ya

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\tan(\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y+\tan^{-1}z)=\dfrac{x+y+z-xyz}{1-(xy+yz+zx)}$$

Now we have $$x+y+z=xyz=-\dfrac p1$$

and $xy+yz+zx=\dfrac q1$

But $\dfrac{x+y+z-xyz}{1-(xy+yz+zx)}$ will be undefined if $xy+yz+zx=q=1$

Comment: thanks , ive solved it finally

Comment: See also : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values, $$n=0,1$$